# Incompatibility between opmac and amstex with xetex

Tags: xetex, opmac, amstex

Consider this simple document:

```
 \input amstex
 \input opmac

 \hyperlinks \Blue \Green

 \maketoc

 \chap Chapter

 \bye
```

If compiled with `pdftex` or `luatex` gives no problems; while with `xetex` gives as error message "! Use of \next doesn't match its definition. ...".  The problem is caused by the activation of hyperlinks (I think the problem resides in the `opmac-xetex.tex` file which is additionally loaded when the xetex engine is detected.)

Looking at the error message I found, as a workaround, this

```
 \input amstex
 \catcode`\@=11
 \let\at@\relax

 \input opmac

 \hyperlinks \Blue \Green

 \maketoc

 \chap Chapter

 \bye
```

but this is not a good solution because I can't restore the chategory code of @ and because I think amstex needs in some way `\at@`.  What is a good solution?

Comment: Why not loading `opmac` before `amstex` which even makes more sense, in my opinion?

Comment: @egreg. Why does it make more sense to you to input opmac before amstex?  Look at the "Intelligent \dots like in
AMSTeX" trick here:  petr.olsak.net/opmac-tricks-e.html.
I think some reason should exists for loading amstex before opmac, if the author of opmac says: "You can do \input amstex before \input opmac".

Comment: @egreg. For example \sec which stands for section in opmac is redefined as secant in amstex.  But the principal reason for not loading amstex after opmac I think lays in the font system of opmac which amstex may alter, but I'm not sure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usage of OPmac with `amstex.tex` may bring problems. For example, you discovered that `amstex.tex` sets the `@` as active. So, users must write:

```
\input amstex \catcode`\@=12
\input opmac
```

You cannot restore `` \catcode`\@=\active `` at beginning of your document when you plan to use the `@` feature in the argument of `\ii` macro (insertion to index) and to sort the index (see the page 6 of OPmac manual). Better solution would be to set catcode of `@` as active only locally when commutative diagram is created:

```
\def\diagram{\begingroup\catcode`@=\active}
\def\enddiagram{\endgroup}
```

Another problem can occur when math formula is included in the argument of `\write` (math formulas in section titles, for example). AMSTeX didn't expect that somebody needs to do something like:

```
\maketoc
...
\sec The function $\sin$
```

You can try it and look to the `*.ref` file. You can see something like this:

```
\Xtoc{1}{\rm }{1}{The function $\mathop {\fam \z@ sin}\let \next \relax \def \countxviii@=\count42{\let \countxviii@=\count42\nolimits \countxviii@=\count42}\futurelet \next \countxviii@=\count42$ }{1}
```

On the other hand, when original definition of `\sin` from plain TeX is used (without `\input amstex`) then you can see in the `*.ref` file:

```
\Xtoc{1}{\rm }{1}{The function $\mathop {\fam 0\tenrm sin}\nolimits $ }{1}
```

And this is robust and works in the TOC (for example) without problems.
If you need to avoid this problem with `amstex.tex` then you must to `\addprotect` many control sequences:

```
\addprotect\sin \addprotect\cos ... etc.
```

Probably next problems occur. I am not sure because I don't know AMSTeX (I have no manual "Joy of TeX").

I strongly recommend to re-implement the features of AMSTeX and not to use the `amstex.tex` directly. If somebody needs to implement some interesting feature from ASMTeX, he/she can sent me email and I can write new [OPmac trick](http://petr.olsak.net/opmac-tricks-e.html) in my www page. This is not problem for me.

Notice about the order of `\input opmac`, `\input amstex`. If OPmac is loaded first then AMSTeX fonts math setting are activated and only static sizes of fonts 10pt/7pt/5pt and CM are available. When you use reverting order, then `\typosize` and `\typoscale` works for math fonts too because math font setting is now done by macro file `ams-math.tex`.

Comment: Is it possible to `\addprotect` some control sequence with an `@` character?  If so, then I think it would be sufficient to `\addprotect` only `\qopname@` which is common to all of `\sin`, `\cos`, ...

Comment: @User yes, it is possible (if catcode of `@` is 11 during `\addprotect`). Your idea will work.

Comment: Before asking you I already tried `\input amstex \catcode'\@=12 \input opmac \catcode'\@=11 \addprotect\qopname@ \catcode'\@=12 \maketoc \chap $\sin$ \bye` but it does not work on the second tex pass.  Why?

Comment: The quote ' instead of the back-quote ` is only to make it format correctly.  Of course, there should be also a `\par` after `\chap $sin$`

Comment: You need to set ``\catcode`\@=11`` during `\input opmac` because the `.ref` file is read during this processing. One little problem occurs when catcode of `@` is 11 during `\input opmac`: the definition of `\iiatsign` is bad. You must re-define it using `\def\iiatsing{@}` after ``\catcode`\@=12``.

Comment: Why is the `.ref` file read during `\input opmac`?  This way one can't make a format out of opmac.  Wouldn't it be better to read the `.ref` file during `\maketoc` or other macros that need the data in the `.ref` file?

Comment: Thank for interesting idea (making format with opmac macros). You can do this. The `formatname.ref` file does not exist during format generation so no special file is read. When you are using such format, you must write `\inputref` at beginning of your document, more precisely before first reference is saved (because it removes the previous version of this file). Maybe you can put `\inputref` to the `\everyjob` of such generated format. I didn't do these experiments.

Comment: I've just tried `\pdfoutput=1 \input etex.src \input opmac \expandafter\everyjob\expandafter{\the\everyjob\inputref} \dump` (compiled with `pdftex -etex -ini <filename.ini>`) and it works :)

Answer (score 4):

`amstex` makes `@` active for usage in the commutative diagram macros and other utilities. You can disable this behavior when loading `opmac` and restore it later.

```
\input amstex

% save the category code of @
\chardef\savedatcatcode=\catcode`@
% restore the standard code
\catcode`@=12

\input opmac

% restore amstex category code of @
\catcode`@=\savedatcatcode

\hyperlinks \Blue \Green

\maketoc

\chap Chapter

\bye
```

If you want to use more sensible names for section and chapters, while saving `\sec` for the secant, you can do it.

```
\input amstex

% save the category code of @
\chardef\savedatcatcode=\catcode`@
% restore the standard code
\catcode`@=12
\let\amstexsec\sec

\input opmac

% restore amstex category code of @
\catcode`@=\savedatcatcode
\let\section\sec
\let\sec\amstexsec
\let\chapter\chap

\hyperlinks \Blue \Green

\maketoc

\chapter Chapter

\section Section

\bye
```

Comment: Note, that `\sec` and `\secans` is mentioned and solved in OPmac trick http://petr.olsak.net/opmac-tricks-e.html#sec

Comment: @wipet Solved? Something like `\sec About $\sec x$` is surely wrong.

Comment: As usual, I don't agree with your opinion. Do you know the context dependent primitives and macros? Secondly, OPmac suggests to use `\sec`, `\secc` and `\chap` for sections etc. User can use another markup but this means that the markup given by OPmac isn't respected.

Comment: @wipet Of course I know about `\span`, `\penalty` and `\kern`, for instance. I believe that they are like that just because of size considerations, which were important at the time TeX was written. I also believe that a command can have contextual dependent definitions but just in order to do the same (or analogous) thing in different situations (like ``\\`` in LaTeX, but this covers `\penalty` and `\kern`). Using the same command name for very different things is wrong (and yes, I think the same about `\span`). Besides, aren't you always blaming LaTeX for being too rigid?